# JPA merge throws exception Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' during flush

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a spring server using hibernate 5.2 and JPA to handle the database.

We have a process that collects a lot of data and saves events based off of that data. It runs daily and there is the potential that these events change values. Sometimes when I try to save these, I get the following exception:

```
15:28:32.819 [pool-6-thread-3] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Duplicate entry 'VAL-below_avg-2017-04-07' for key 'PRIMARY'
Query is: insert into event_date (description, period, time, date, symbol, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Query is:
insert into event_date (description, period, time, date, symbol, type) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
[org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
15:28:32.822 [pool-6-thread-3] ERROR org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionMapperStandardImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:278)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504)
```

We're not doing anything fancy here. We process data. We create new objects. We pass them into the following method in our DAO:

```
public void saveOrUpdate(List<EventDate> events) {
    for (EventDate e : events) {
        try{
            entityManager.merge(e);
        }catch(Exception e1){
            logger.error("Something broke!");
        }
    }
}
```

I've gone through about a dozen similar questions, but in all of them, the problem seemed to be caused by some sort of directional relationship with another object. In my case, there is no such thing. I also saw some people suggest it was an issue with not having hashcode and equals, so I implemented those to no avail.

My Entity class looks like the following (there are many Entities that inherit EventDate, but they mostly just add some meta properties here and there, I don't think the issue lies with them:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "event_date")  
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)  
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING, length=255)
@DiscriminatorOptions(insert=false)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public abstract class EventDate implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId 
    private SymDateTypeId id;

    @Column(columnDefinition=COLUMN_DATETIME)
    private String time = "UNKNOWN";

    @Column(columnDefinition=COLUMN_TEXT)
    private String description;

    @Column(columnDefinition=COLUMN_VARCHAR20)
    private String period;

    //Getters/Setters/Hashcode/Equals omitted...
}

@Embeddable
public class SymDateTypeId implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String symbol = "UNKNOWN";
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String date = "UNKNOWN";
    @Column(nullable=false)
    private String type;

    //Getters and setters omitted...

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((date == null) ? 0 : date.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((symbol == null) ? 0 : symbol.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((type == null) ? 0 : type.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        SymDateTypeId other = (SymDateTypeId) obj;
        if (date == null) {
            if (other.date != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!date.equals(other.date))
            return false;
        if (symbol == null) {
            if (other.symbol != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!symbol.equals(other.symbol))
            return false;
        if (type == null) {
            if (other.type != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!type.equals(other.type))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Duplicate entry 'VAL-below_avg-2017-04-07' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

definitely indicates that you already have a related row in you database. Try to find out why you save events twice and all is fine. You might add also log entries to your source.

Comment: Yes, I recognize that. I guess the thing that throws me for a loop here is that hibernate's saveOrUpdate didn't have this problem. While I know merge and saveOrUpdate are subtly different, I was under the impression that that was one of the cases it was supposed to be able to handle. For what it's worth, I ended up basically doing what you suggest- I delete all the past records that could potentially match and then fill in the new ones. It just doesn't seem like that is how it's supposed to have to work.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your problem. Indeed merging existing entities shall update them if the given id already exists.